# How to test a ProducerInterceptor in a Kafka Streams topology?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the requirement to pipe records from one topic to another, keeping the original partitioning intact (the original producer use a non-native Kafka partitioner). The reason for this is that the source topic is uncompressed, and we wish to "reprocess" the data into a compressed topic - transparently, from the point of view of the original producers and consumers.

I have a trivial KStreams topology that does this using a `ProducerInterceptor`:

```java
void buildPipeline(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    streamsBuilder
            .stream(topicProperties.getInput().getName())
            .to(topicProperties.getOutput().getName());
}
```

together with:

```yaml
interceptor.classes: com.acme.interceptor.PartitionByHeaderInterceptor
```

This interceptor looks in the message headers (which contain a partition Id header) and simply redirects the `ProducerRecord` to the original topic:

```java
@Override
public ProducerRecord<K, V> onSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> record) {
    int partition = extractSourcePartition(record);
    return new ProducerRecord<>(record.topic(), partition, record.timestamp(), record.key(), record.value(), record.headers());
}
```

My question is: **how can I test this interceptor in a test topology (i.e. integration test)**?

I've tried adding:

```java
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix("interceptor.classes"),
                PartitionByHeaderInterceptor.class.getName());
```

(which is how I enable the interceptor in production code)

to my test topology stream configuration, but my interceptor is not called by the test topology driver.

Is what I'm trying to do currently technically possible?

Comment: As an aside, the only thing that I've been able to find via Google was [this](https://engineering.fundingcircle.com/blog/2017/11/26/testing-kafka-streams-topologies-with-kafka-interceptors/) blog post which is... not very informative.

Comment: Unrelated , but adding `compression.type` into configs should be fairly transparent for producers and consumers. I'm not sure how that relates to repartitioning.

Comment: Adding `compression.type` would only compress new data. We wish to compress existing data to reduce the storage footprint. Also, I explicitly do not want to repartition in this case, but as you said, that's not quite related to this case.

Comment: To be more specific: this is a data migration scenario where input and output is the same, just that the output topic is compressed on the broker side.

Comment: So, how are you actually testing this code? Or that is the question? `TopologyTestDriver` should still call the interceptor methods. I don't know how you'd test compression, through, since the consumer would automatically decompress the events.

Comment: Yes, that is the question. Adding `interceptor.classes` to my `TopologyTestDriver` configuration has seemingly no effect and the interceptor is *not* called. I've slightly reworded the question to hopefully make this clearer. I do not intend to test the compression since that is outside of the scope of my test - a one-time script that verifies topic configuration should suffice in that case, since the migration is also a one-off.